# How to add one keybinding for all shortcuts in wpf xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, key-bindings

I need to know how to add one keybinding tag and how to reuse the same tag for all keybindings.Also any possibilities of having a keybinding framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can derive a command, attach a Key Gesture event and use the same command everywhere....